# Place div near fixed div

Tags: html, css

I want to place a div fixed on the left and near I want to place other div.

Imagine a twitter webpage, I want to fixed the left panel (where you write yout tweets) and near I want to place the panel where you read tweets.

Now I have the following code:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id=fixed-menu>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
  </div>
</div>

#fixed-menu {
     position:fixed;
     background: #fff;
     padding: 10px;
     top:60px;
     left: 10px;
     width:300px;
     max-width: 300px;
 }

#content {
    background: #fff;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

In this way, the div with id="content" appear on left so, the fixed-menu doesn't appear, because it is under content div.

If I use margin-left in #content the error is solved, but I don't want use that, any other solution?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried using floats?....

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on the issue that your having. Do you just need to have the fixed menu appear above the div#content? Because you could muse the z-index property.

Comment: You're missing quotes in your HTML code and you are also not referencing the background-color correctly... Also based off of what you are giving us, your fixed menu is being represented below your content, is that what you want?

Comment: The quotes are definitely significant. However, the "background" property can be used with just a color code. It's the shorthand form and the color code is the first property in the shorthand. The rest of the values are essentially filled in as null. So, it's fine. =)

Comment: I appreciate the insight on that, @bboysupaman! Thank you! :)

Comment: I want put the #fixed-menu div on the left and next I want put the #content div. The problem is that #fixed-menu contain the fixed property so the #content div appears above #fixed-menu (on the left, and I want put it next to the #fixed-menu div not above it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the first things to note is that by putting a position Fixed on div#fixed-menu breaks it out of the normal document flow. What this means is that the other block/inline level elements do not know about it. Also by making it fixed, you make it fixed relative to the window. If you want it "fixed" within the container and not to a certain point on the screen I would go with position:absolute and then a position:relative on it's parent container.

Either way, the problem you're experiencing where div#content doesn't respect the position of the fixed element, is due to the fact that the fixed element is no longer part of the normal document flow. Adding a z-index to div#fixed-menu should bring it above the content. However, you will see overlapping and will have to account of the offset of div#content with either margin on div#content or padding on the parent container.

If you look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f38aj/

## css:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    height: 700px;
    padding: 0 0 0 320px;
}

#fixed-menu {
     position: fixed;
     background: red;
     padding: 10px;
     top:8px;
     left: 8px;
     width: 300px;
     max-width: 300px;
 }

#content {
    background: blue;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

If you notice we create padding in the container, where we end up overlaying the div#container object.

we have a fixed container on the left while the right side content will scroll with the page. If you can come up with a non fixed solution it might be better, as there are phone browsers like older versions of iOS that will take anything that is position fixed and replace it with position absolute.

A side note, working with fixed/absolute positioning is useful especially in some crazy cases, but it does require a little more due diligence on your/your teams parts to maintain. If you start getting into z-indexes you might want to look at a library like less or sass just to create global css variables, which will make it easier to manage what can turn into an almost unmanageable experience.

hope that helps.

Comment: Your reply is a good reply, but I am trying avoid absolute values (padding) because I want design a responsive design. There is other solution or maybe I should think about doenst use fixed?. Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what the final product should look like/behave like? If you don't want fixed elements, but you want the illusion of one side fixed while the other side scrolls. You could just do something where the Fixed-menu is floated left and the content div is floated up next to it. Then the content div can have a height/width with overflow:scroll. (this isn't the best experience for mobile users as there are a few issues w/ scrollable divs in some mobile os's, but iOS and Android have fixed alot of these issues in their recent releases) So it does cover 'maintstream'